# How do I condition this GridView to have only one cell with the same value?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, gridview

Here is my problem. I have this Grid:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvTest" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="IdTask" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="4" 
                OnPageIndexChanging="gvTest_PageIndexChanging" PagerStyle-CssClass="pagerGrid" CssClass="gvTest" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerGrid" 
                RowStyle-CssClass="rowsGrid" OnRowCommand="gvTest_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvTest_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IdTask" HeaderText="ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Task" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="User" HeaderText="User" />
                   <asp:TemplateField>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Button ID="btnLoad" runat="server" Text="Bugs" CssClass="btn" data-task-id='<%# Eval("IdTask") %>'></asp:Button>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnProgress" runat="server" Text="TakeInProgress" CommandName="progress" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'></asp:Button>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:TemplateField>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="btnFiles" CssClass="btnFiles" runat="server" ImageUrl="img/files.png.png"/>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

All values come from a mysql database. In the database i have multiple tables but the ones relevant to this problem are:

tasks table : idtask,iduser,name,description

stages table : idstage, idtask, idstate //the connection table

states table: idstate, name

Ok so in the states table i have only 3 : inWaiting, inProgress, Finished

As you can see in the state column of the grid populates each task with its respective state .. the row is colored in red when button is clicked and hide the button once the state becames inProgress

Here is what the codebehind looks like and what i have tried, i only managed to color the row hide button and update the state to inProgress:

```
protected void gvTest_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "progress")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); //converts the row index stored in command argument property to an integer
            GridViewRow row = gvTest.Rows[index]; //retrieve the row that contains the button clicked by the user from the rows collection
            string state = (row.Cells[3].Text); //gets the value of the cell
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(gvTest.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString()); //gets the primary key value

            string sqlUpdateState = "UPDATE states SET IdState=@IdState WHERE IdTask = @IdTask";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlUpdateState, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTask", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdState", 1);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            LoadGridData();
        }

    }

    protected void gvTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string state = (e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                if (state == "inProgress")
                {
                    cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What i need now is that only a task can be inProgress at a time .. something like if I clicked the button on another row the previous state which was inProgress to change its state to inWaiting and the new task becames inProgress 
Can you help? 
I tried to explain it as best i could .. english is not my primary language. If you have any questions please ask. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can understand is, you want single task at a time to be 'in progress'.

You can update the state of a task which is 'in progress' to 'in waiting' when changing other task's state to 'in Progress'.

Try this code.

```
protected void gvTest_RowCommand (object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "progress")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); //converts the row index stored in command argument property to an integer
        GridViewRow row = gvTest.Rows[index]; //retrieve the row that contains the button clicked by the user from the rows collection
        string state = (row.Cells[3].Text); //gets the value of the cell
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(gvTest.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString()); //gets the primary key value
        string sqlChangeStateToWaiting = "UPDATE task set IDState = @IdState where IDState = @IdStateInProgress";

        MySqlCommand cmdChangeStateToWaiting = new MySqlCommand(sqlUpdateState, conn);
        cmdChangeStateToWaiting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdState ", "id for in waiting");
        cmdChangeStateToWaiting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdStateInProgress", "id for in progress");

        string sqlUpdateState = "UPDATE task SET IdState=@IdState WHERE IdTask = @IdTask";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlUpdateState, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTask", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdState", 1);

        conn.Open();
        cmdChangeStateToWaiting.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        LoadGridData();
    }

}
```

Comment: Omg yes! Thank you so much! it works .. i just had a blockage and couldn't figure out how i should update them :)